# How can I design this database so the table have less Null block in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with sqlite so the space is a issue for me.
I want a table to store the history temperature data for some cities. The table would be like

```
city_name      2018_04_04  2018_04_03  2018_04_02 ......
```

But the thing is the range of these history temperature records are different for different cities. Just for example, for New York, the temperature records starts from 1800 AD, the temperature records for London starts from 1600 AD. 
So there will be huge space filled with Null if I build a table whose column starts with 1600 AD. So far as I known the Null takes also space if the data is float.

How should I build this table so it will be "smarter" and filled with more useful data? Or at least "force" the Null does not take any space?

Comment: How about creating a table with four fields, `id`, `city_name`, `measurement_date`, and `temperature`, then just fill it with the dates you have?

Comment: @JLe Thnx lod, you just saved my ass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add each day as column but add a date-column and write the date into this column:

```
city_name |       date | temperature
____________________________________
 New York | 2018_04_04 |        40.3
 New York | 2018_04_03 |        38.3
```

If you want to save some memory add a city table and only write the city_fk into the temperature table.

```
ID  City
1   London
2   New York
```

```
CityID |   date   | temperature
   2    2018-04-04     40.3
   2    2018-04-03     38.3
```